# GKE: Modify existing cluster - remove node tags and change network

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I created a Kubernetes cluster with the following CLI command:

`gcloud container clusters create some-cluster --tags=some-tag --network=some-network`

I would now like to:

1. Disable the `--tags` option, so that new nodes/VMs are created *without* the tag `some-tag`. (Optional: Remove the tag from existing machines, which should be possible through `gcloud compute instances remove-tags`.)
2. Disable the `--network` flag, returning the cluster to the default GCP network.

Are either of these operations possible, or will I have to re-create the cluster?

For context, I was using the node tags and networking rules to route outgoing network traffic through a single GCE instance serving as a NAT gateway. I now want to turn this routing off.

Comment: You could make a new pool in your cluster without the tags? And then remove the default pool?

Answer (score 7):

Currently, its not possible to update cluster network and remove tags for existing cluster using the gcloud command. I have verified this information using the gcloud container clusters update command [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/update). Additionally, [alpha](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/container/clusters/update) and [beta](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/container/clusters/update) command don't provide this feature yet. API doc also provides information related to different configuration which can be changed.

As a workaround, I was able to remove one of the tags using the rolling update feature within the instance group setting:

> 1. Go to instance template of some-cluster -> select the template
> 2. Click (copy from the top of instance template)-> Remove the tag -> creates a new template
> 3. Select the some-cluster Instance Group-> click on rolling update -> change the instance template to the one you created -> update

If you change the network in step-2, I was not able to select the instance template with the new network in step-3. Changing the tag alone won’t solve your purpose, it's better to create a new cluster.

If you are interested to update tags and network using the gcloud command, I suggest creating a feature request (FR) in [Public Issue tracker](http://%20https://issuetracker.google.com/).