# Change Kubernetes Instance Template to open HTTPS port

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I was using NodePort to host a webapp on Google Container Engine (GKE). It allows you to directly point your domains to the node IP address, instead of an expensive Google load balancer. Unfortunately, instances are created with HTTP ports blocked by default, and an update locked down manually changing the nodes, as they are now created using and Instance Group/and an Immutable Instance Template.

**I need to open port 443 on my nodes, how do I do that with Kubernetes or GCE? Preferably in an update resistant way.**

[image]

Related github question: https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/issues/502

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 2023-06-23

At some point Google added the ability to add network tags to your node pool... So now you can directly add http-server, https-server and it will work as expected.

---

Update: A deamonset with a nodeport can handle the port opening for you. nginx/k8s-ingress has a nodeport on 443 which gets exposed by a custom firewall rule. the GCE UI will not show「Allow HTTPS traffic」as checked, because its not using the default rule.

---

You can do everything you do on the GUI Google Cloud Console using the Cloud SDK, most easily through the Google Cloud Shell. Here is the command for adding a network tag to a running instance. This works, even though the GUI disabled the ability to do so

```
gcloud compute instances add-tags gke-clusty-pool-0-7696af58-52nf --zone=us-central1-b --tags https-server,http-server
```

This also works on the beta, meaning it should continue to work for a bit.
See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/scripting-gcloud for examples on how to automate this. Perhaps consider running on a webhook when downtime is detected. Obviously none of this is ideal.

Alternatively, you can change the templates themselves. With this method you can also add a startup to new nodes, which allows you do do things like fire a webhook with the new IP Address for a round robin low downtime dynamic dns.

Source (he had the opposite problem, his problem is our solution): https://stackoverflow.com/a/51866195/370238

Comment: Worked with a 1.14 cluster and node upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Using port 443 on your Kubernetes nodes is not a standard practice. If you look at the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) you and see the kubelet option `--service-node-port-range` which defaults to `30000-32767`. You could change it to `443-32767` or something. Note that every port under `1024` is restricted to [root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16564/why-are-the-first-1024-ports-restricted-to-the-root-user-only).

In summary, it's not a good idea/practice to run your Kubernetes services on port `443`. A more typical scenario would be an external nginx/haproxy proxy that sends traffic to the NodePorts of your service.  The other option you mentioned is using a cloud load balancer but you'd like to avoid that due to costs.

Comment: This is a more common now as people are using AWS Route 53 as an external load balancer, but hosting the K8s machines on GCP or multi cloud. Also useful for deployments exposed via an intranet LB

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, if nodes can be destroyed and recreated themselves , how are you going to rest assured that certain service behind port reliably available on production w/o any sort of load balancer which takes care of route orchestration diverting port traffic to new node(s)

Comment: nginx/kubernetes-ingress can be installed in the cluster to do orchestration. You can use DNS api and GCE api's with gcloud to make sure the nodes have a good configuration after a k8s update or autoscale.